# How execute other prompt when prompt previous is true on Yeoman?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman

How execute prompt2 when prompt1 is true on Yeoman as shown below?

```
var prompts = [
  {name: 'prompt1', message: 'Ask 1?'},
  {name: 'prompt2', message: 'Ask 2?'}
];
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Yeoman uses a thing called [Inquirer.js](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js) for the prompt system. Here's an example of how you can ask Question 2 if Question 1 was true:

```
inquirer.prompt([{
  name: 'movie',
  type: 'confirm',
  message: 'Have you seen a movie lately?'
}, {
  when: function (response) {
    return response.movie;
  },
  name: 'good-or-not',
  message: 'Sweet! Was it any good?'
}], function (response) {});
```

From the Inquirer.js documentation:

**when**: *(Function)* Receive the current user answers hash and should return true or false depending on wheter or not this question should be asked.

Comment: How would you add on a question if it was true though?

Comment: @cameronroe If the user answers 'no' to the question 'Have you seen a movie lately?' then the next message will not display. To add another question after 'Sweet! Was it any good?', add another when: function(response){} with the same syntax. You can also change the type for subsequent questions.

Comment: @Our_Benefactors, the `first argument` in the `when()` method is the `answers-hash`.  So if you don't have the required answer for the question, you can `return false;` in the `method function`.  For example : `when: function(ans){ if(ans.prompt1 === false) {return false;} else {return true;}}`.  Good Luck...

Comment: Is there a way to pass the params in when to the prompt? I generated a list in the when and I need to pass that list as the choices for the current promt.